# CSS Submit Button with Loading Animation has a hover effect division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button with a loading animation inside and when I hover it I want to display a gradient effect as a whole thing.

I manage to do it but if you move the cursor over the loading effect and the text you will notice the division between these two.

Please take a look at the following snippet which shows my problem:

```js
document.getElementById("search").onclick = function() {
  var hiddeninputs = document.getElementById("loading");
  hiddeninputs.style.display = "inline-flex";
  $("#loading").delay(1500).fadeOut();
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#loading {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #004E98;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: round 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes round {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}

.btn-search {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 12%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #00386d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  ext-align: center;
  background-color: #004E98;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(25, 25, 25, .3);
}

#button-search:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #004E98;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004E98, #3498db);
}

#button-search:active {
  background-color: #003465;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

#search {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: hidden;
  background-color: #004E98;
  color: #fff;
}

#search:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #004E98;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004E98, #3498db);
}

#search:active {
  background-color: #003465;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-search" id="button-search">
  <input type="submit" id="search" value="Buscar" onclick="showHide()">
  <div id="loading" class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just have `<button type='submit'>Buscar</button>` instead of a `div` that contains an `input`. That way you can just style one element.

Comment: because , i want to have the loading status and the button together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had another background on the input element `#search` and that created another background on top of the background of the div `.btn-search`. I made them transparent and removed the outline that appears around the input on `:active` and `:focus`.

```js
 document.getElementById("search").onclick = function() {
  var hiddeninputs = document.getElementById("loading");
  hiddeninputs.style.display="inline-flex";
  $("#loading").delay(1500).fadeOut();
 }
```

```css
 .hidden{
  display: none;
 }
 #loading{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #004E98;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: round 2s linear infinite;
 }
 @keyframes round{
  from{transform: rotate(0deg)}
  to{transform:rotate(360deg)}
 }
 .btn-search{
 width:20%;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin:10px;
  height: 12%;
 margin-top:25px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 2px solid #00386d;
 border-radius: 5px;
 ext-align: center;
 background-color: #004E98;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(25,25,25,.3);
}
#button-search:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
    background: #004E98;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004E98, #3498db);
}
#button-search:active{
background-color: #003465;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
#search{
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  padding-left:25px;
  padding-right:25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

#search:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
}

#search:active{
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

#search:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-search" id="button-search">
  <input type="submit" id="search" value="Buscar" onclick="showHide()">
  <div id="loading" class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a transparent background to the input using `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>CSS LOADING SPINNERS</title>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <style>
 .hidden{
  display: none;
 }
 #loading{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-top-color: #004E98;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: round 2s linear infinite;
 }
 @keyframes round{
  from{transform: rotate(0deg)}
  to{transform:rotate(360deg)}
 }
 .btn-search{
 width:20%;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin:10px;
  height: 12%;
 margin-top:25px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: 2px solid #00386d;
 border-radius: 5px;
 ext-align: center;
 background-color: #004E98;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(25,25,25,.3);
}
#button-search:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
    background: #004E98;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004E98, #3498db);
}
#button-search:active{
background-color: #003465;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
#search{
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
  padding-left:25px;
  padding-right:25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  color: #fff;
}

/* #search:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
    background: #004E98;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #004E98, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004E98, #3498db);
} */

#search:active{
  background-color: #003465;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
 
 </style>

 <div class="btn-search" id="button-search">
  <input type="submit" id="search" value="Buscar" onclick="showHide()">
  <div id= "loading" class="hidden"></div>
 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("search").onclick = function() {
  var hiddeninputs = document.getElementById("loading");
  hiddeninputs.style.display="inline-flex";
  $("#loading").delay(1500).fadeOut();
 }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```